# How to get details of all the child at same time in single list view from real-time database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am able to retrieve details of a single child on the list view but not all the child from firebase database. I want to access the child directly.

Here is my code

[database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vuwt.png)

[emulator pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNNsd.png)

```
 public class ViewDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static final String TAG = "ViewDatabase";
 private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
 private ListView mListView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_database_layout);
 mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
   databaseReference = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("hello");
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

  }
 private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        userinfo user = snapshot.getValue(userinfo.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + user.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Mobile: " + user.getMob());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Vehicle: " + user.getVehicle());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: Address: " + user.getaddress());

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(user.getName());
        array.add(user.getMob());
        array.add(user.getVehicle());
        array.add(user.getaddress());
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new array and adapter for every item in the snapshot. You should only create the array only once, add all items to it, and then create an adapter from the array:

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        userinfo user = snapshot.getValue(userinfo.class);

        array.add(user.getName());
        array.add(user.getMob());
        array.add(user.getVehicle());
        array.add(user.getaddress());
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
 }
```

With this you'll end up with 4 items in the list view for each child node in the database. While this technically works, it's probably not what you want. A more common representation would be to add a single item to the array for every user:

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        userinfo user = snapshot.getValue(userinfo.class);

        array.add(user.getName()+" ("+user.getMob()+")\n"+user.getVehicle()+"\n"user.getaddress());
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
 }
```

I also recommend looking into [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/), which has a [FirebaseListAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview) and other classes that take away the need for creating your own adapter for common cases.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference helloRef = rootRef.child("hello");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String address = ds.child("address").getValue(String.class);
            String mob = ds.child("mob").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String vehicle = ds.child("vehicle").getValue(String.class);
            array.add(address + " / " + mob + " / " + name + " / " + vehicle);
            Log.d("TAG", address + " / " + mob + " / " + name + " / " + vehicle);
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
helloRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: nothing happens as do i need to use array adapter for this

Comment: why you have used String .class

Comment: Because all those values are of type `String`.

Comment: no error in this, (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

Comment: You need to put `this, ` in front of the (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array) in those parentheses. As Frank said, another aprroach will be, to user [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).